# Using presistence.js to create cross-platform database(websql or indexeddb whichever is supported by browser)

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, persistence, windows-phone

I'm newbie in [persistence.js](http://persistencejs.org/) and would like to know how can i use it for my application that will be developed for iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

Any code example will be very helpful.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to consider alternative [javascript database library YDN-DB](http://git.yathit.com/ydn-db/wiki/Home), which I created. It has reasonable good documentations and example codes.

It is pretty straight forward to use it. Any problem, just drop a comments or questions.

Comment: Yes. It has both IndexedDB and WebSQL storage mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks @Kyaw it worked for me. I didn't put the deps.js, core.js in the project folder due to which error was coming. after putting those files everything was working as it should be.

Comment: welcome. you shouldn't need deps.js or core.js. Any *one* of those minified js files should enough.

Comment: I did checked with the minified js and is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: The library is not working properly in IE10. Error: SCRIPT5007: Object expected in ydn-db-min-0.9.3.js, line 60 character 435

Comment: Can you please test this ASAP. It's urgent for me to implement this thing.

Comment: Hey that issue is resolved. Sorry I did something wrong with the transaction and query so that error was coming. Thanks anyway.

Comment: IE10 crash more than 10 times just to see dev console, I am tire of it. I am tired of it, will try after win 8 rc update. how did you resolved?

Comment: Actually there was error in the transaction structure so the records were not been fetched from database.

Comment: can you give me your email address? Have some important questions about the library.

Comment: You can find It on the source files.

Comment: Can't find anywhere. Anyways what I want is to fetch records from 2 different tables having primarykey, foreign key relationship. some rows from main table and some from the other table that is referencing.

Comment: I tried the example given in this section http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/starting/transaction.html. But got error Undefined get on line number xxx.

Comment: Regarding library problem please fine and issue https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/issues/new on the repository. Currently I am updating documentation, so I will update soon.

Comment: Could you explain more detail? I could not get your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17390/discussion-between-rishi-and-kyaw)